# Alternativeness... or not?

Tags: ontology, paradox, possible-worlds

We recognize as an axiom that events in our reality can occur in different ways.
It is about facts, models that combine facts and our reactions.
I call it *alternativeness*.

Here I *will not ask*: whether alternativeness is an objective property of the Universe or is it a purely subjective phenomenon.

I asked myself a very simple question: *can this quality be totally absent?* Could a sentient being never have a clue, an idea that things could be different?

When I started thinking about this topic, I suddenly realized:
as itself, *the assumption about absence of alternativeness is... alternativeness!*

I wonder if this is a tautology or some kind of paradox? Is there any mention of such a paradox?

Comment: "We recognize as an axiom..." Why? What does it mean?

Comment: "the assumption about absence of alternativeness is... alternativeness!" Is it a tautology? No. Is it a paradox? If an assumption leads to a contradiction, this means that the assumption is false.

Comment: you might want to read some of the works of the Buddhist philosopher Nagarjuna.

Answer (score -1):

I'd relate it to group theory and symmetry transformations, and relate it fundamentally to intentionality (elaborating possible positions and manipulations from current situation). A robot or computer could simulate intelligence without intentionality.